# Adding space in a dynamic query sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

i am creating a dynamic query in which i need to put a space in a db field when retrieving the eg is as follows when i give single quotes its not accepting

`DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(8000)` 
 
`SET @QUERY='SELECT DATENAME(MM,getdate())+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107),9)+SUBSTRING(CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),12,6) + ' '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),2) AS CurrentDate'` 
`EXECUTE (@QUERY)`

the aim is to put a space in between hh:mm and AM/PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double up the quotes

```
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(8000) 
SET @QUERY='SELECT DATENAME(MM,getdate())+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107),9)+SUBSTRING(CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),12,6) + '' ''+ RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),2) AS CurrentDate' 
EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

But why is this dynamic? Just run it in line

```
SELECT
   DATENAME(MM,getdate())+
   RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107),9)+
   SUBSTRING(CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),12,6) + 
   ' '+
   RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),2) AS CurrentDate
```

Or format in the client code...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @QUERY='SELECT DATENAME(MM,getdate())
+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107),9)
+SUBSTRING(CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),12,6) 
+ '' '' 
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),2) AS CurrentDate'
    EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

To escape the single quotes, use two of them next to each other.

Comment: @FilipScript Thank you for the reply its working in sql server but when i call the same using datatable its getting null. i am simply writing it as a procedure.

Comment: @FilpScript Sorry it was not the code error actually my length of the varchar was the problem when i increased the length it started performing good. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to doubling up quotes (and assuming the need for dynamic SQL is real) is to simply use Char(32)

```
 DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @QUERY='SELECT DATENAME(MM,getdate())
+RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107),9)
+SUBSTRING(CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),12,6) 
+ Char(32)
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),100),2) AS CurrentDate'
    EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

Comment: It absoluty correct OK, but it is a bit annoying when you often switch betwenn MS-SQLServer and Oracle. The later calls the same function CHR. '' '' works for both and is more readable.